# passing a two dimensional dynamic pointer array as an argument to a function in cython

Tags: python, c, arrays, pointers, cython

In my code, I am trying to define a dynamic array with changing number of the rows and columns, depends on the new conditions inside the function, meaning I might add more rows or columns. I tried to make two dimensional pointer arrays and I want to be able to pass this 2-D pointer array as an argument to a function.

This is the small part of my code:

**Update: test.pyx**

```
from libc.string cimport memset
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
from cython.view cimport array as cvarray
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
from libc.math cimport log, exp
from cython_gsl cimport *
import ctypes
cdef gsl_rng *r = gsl_rng_alloc(gsl_rng_mt19937)
cdef int** zeros2(dim):
     assert len(dim) == 2
     cdef int i
     cdef int **matrix
     matrix = <int**> malloc(sizeof(int*) * dim[0])
     for i from 0 <= i < dim[0]:
         matrix[i] = <int*> malloc(sizeof(int) * dim[1])
         memset(matrix[i], 0, sizeof(int) * dim[1])
     return matrix

@cython.cdivision(True)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
cdef void generator(double* alpha,int* D, double* m):

     cdef Py_ssize_t i
     for i from 0 <= i < D[0]:            
        m[i]=gsl_ran_beta(r, alpha[0], 1)
     return

@cython.cdivision(True)     
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)     
cdef void initializer(double* alpha, int* D, int* N, double* m, int** Z ):
     cdef int i, j         

     generator(alpha, D, &m[0])

     for i from 0 <= i < D[0]:
         for j from 0 <= j < N[0]: 
             Z[j][i]= gsl_ran_bernoulli(r, m[i]) 
             print Z[j][i]
     return

def run(int n, int d, double alpha):
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=1, mode='c'] mu=np.empty((d,), dtype=ctypes.c_double)
    cdef int **Z = zeros2((n, d))

    initializer(&alpha, &d, &n,  &mu[0], <int **>(&Z[0][0]) )
```

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from numpy import get_include
import numpy
import cython_gsl
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
ext_modules = [
    Extension(
        "test",
        ["test.pyx"],
        libraries=cython_gsl.get_libraries(),
        library_dirs=[cython_gsl.get_library_dir()],
        include_dirs=[numpy.get_include(), cython_gsl.get_include()])

]
ext_modules = cythonize(ext_modules)

setup(
    name='test',
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext})
```

**Update:**

The code gets compiled but when I import the `run function` in python I get this error:

```
>>> import test
>>> test.run( 10, 4,0.9)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I am not sure the 2-dimensional array that I defined is the best approach to solve my problem of defining a dynamical array and what is the reason I got this error?

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate problem is that:

```
<int **>(&Z[0][0])
```

takes the address of the first element of the first row and casts it to an `int**`. It's actually an `int*` (because it's the address of an `int`). Therefore the memory that `initializer` writes to is nonsense and you get a segmentation fault. Casts are often an indication that you're doing something wrong.

You just need to pass `Z` which is already an `int**`.

Comment: thanks for the answer! It fixed this error but my main question is what is the best way to define a dynamic array? What about gsl_matrix? How does it work in cython? I also need to find the inverse of a square matrix and I guess it would be a good option, right? What do you recommend?

Comment: Why not just use using numpy arrays? But I don't really know. I made this answer "community wiki" because I saw an obvious bug and thought it was worth pointing that out, but I didn't want to answer the full question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `n`, `d` and `alpha` are Python variables, so `&n` is not something you can do. You can change `run` to `cdef` function, or maybe create a temporary version:

```
cdef int _n = n;
```

and then pass `&_n`

However, based on your code, what's the point of passing a pointer to these three variables, anyway? You don't modify them. You can simply pass them without a pointer.